# AWS API Gateway get Api key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get the actual key from an API Key in "API Keys" of API Gateway.

```
AmazonApiGateway client = AmazonApiGatewayClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("my region").build();

GetApiKeysRequest req = new GetApiKeysRequest();        
GetApiKeysResult keys = client.getApiKeys(req);

ApiKey key = keys.getItems().get(0); // just get the first one.. 

System.out.println(key.getId());
System.out.println(key.getName());
System.out.println(key.getValue());
```

Was hoping **getValue()** would provide the actual key, but it's null..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're setting [includeValues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/apigateway/model/GetApiKeysRequest.html#setIncludeValues-java.lang.Boolean-) to `true`:

```
req.setIncludeValues(true);
```